# Cannot render css in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I modified main.min.css and main.full.css (setting another color of background) and page now cannot render css. It's just a HTML.

***Master page:*** (shortened version with links)

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ZASshop.master.cs" Inherits="ZASshop.NET.ZASshop" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="ZAScontrols"    Namespace="ZAScontrols"    TagPrefix="zas" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="MasterHead" runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <link href="/App_Firma/css/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link href="/App_Firma/css/firm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="/App_Firma/DayPilot/Themes/scheduler_8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="/App_Firma/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*at the end of this file link to script:*

```
<script src="/App_Firma/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

*and I also got a warnings and error in Chrome console:*

> LoginPage.aspx:7 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred
>   with MIME type text/html:
>   "http://localhost/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApp_Firma%2fcss%2fcustom.css".
>   LoginPage.aspx:7 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred
>   with MIME type text/html:
>   "http://localhost/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApp_Firma%2fcss%2ffirm.css".
>   LoginPage.aspx:7 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred
>   with MIME type text/html:
>   "http://localhost/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApp_Firma%2fcss%2fmain.min.css".
>   LoginPage.aspx:7 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred
>   with MIME type text/html:
>   "http://localhost/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApp_Firma%2fDayPilot%2fThemes%2fscheduler_8.css".
>   LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fApp_Firma%2fjs%2fapp.min.js:2 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Which library you have modified? Is it bootstrap one or other one?

Comment: @PowerStar I just modified main.min.css and main.full.css. And maybe some of .aspx pages.

Comment: What kind of edit have you made? What css file was? Where you using a library?

Comment: Please confirm you have mentioned file name correctly.

Comment: @Ema.jar I modified main.min.css and main.full.css and some of .aspx files, I don't know exactly. What do you mean where?

Comment: @PowerStar confirmed

Comment: If you look at the error messages, it is pretty obvious that the system is trying to redirect the requests for those stylesheets via the login page ... so you somehow managed to make your stylesheets content that is only visible to logged-in users, which is rather not what you want ...

Comment: @CBroe okay, so what should I do?

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see. Seems that you've validation schema in web.config which redirect all CSS file requests to a page (suspected login page), which means you need to allow anonymous user requesting CSS files.

Comment: Is it downloading, when you open any css file from browser?

Comment: @PowerStar I inserted this to browser C:\inetpub\net_zshop_mur_001_sk_murat\App_Firma\css\main.min.css and it opens the content, but not downloading

Comment: what is the output is it loaded?? Basically try to run from IIS server. i.e http://localhost/<filename>.min.css

Comment: @PowerStar Yes, output is loaded. Now, with localhost, it seems redirecting me to login page, but I'm not sure if I'm giving the right path to main.min.css

Comment: Are you using any authentication??

Comment: @PowerStar yes, on LoginPage.aspx - path = "/" protection = "All"

Comment: yes, i understood.  I have mentioned possible answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-
awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-
awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css"/>
```

you need to close the label with '/'

check this post too, seems to be the same problem:

[Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html in ASP.NET IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089070/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-in-a)

Comment: try to add `type="text/css"` and close properly meta tags too

Comment: Stays the same. I think probably it will be something with web.config

Comment: if this doesn`t work, can you share the whole file code, plz?

Comment: It has 46k characters, which is above the limit of 30k characters, where can I place it?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089070/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-in-a

Comment: I have in MIME types .css (inherited)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150578/discussion-between-ferus7-and-julius-marko).

Answer (score 0):

You must add .css MIME type with text/css value into IIS. Currently, the web server does not understand what .css means.

This will work when the content-type response header value is set to text/css.

Comment: I have in MIME types .css (inherited)

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the css files and images from getting authenticated as following in the configuration file. Using the location tag you can exclude a single file or a directory.

```
<location path="<relatevie path of your css files>">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Should I add it to the end of Web.config? Can you give an example of relative path?

Comment: Inside configuration tag.

Comment: Yes in your case "/App_Firma/".

Comment: Should I use "\App_firma\css\" ?

Comment: If you want to allow script also then use /App_firma/ or only css then include css directory too.

Comment: Hi @JúliusMarko What happend??

Comment: Ok then just add "App_Firma"

Comment: Now it loads the page, but without css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150590/discussion-between-power-star-and-julius-marko).