# import css under css violate the rules of CSP and not loading

Tags: c#, css, web-config, content-security-policy

I am working c# MVC 4 web application. In that, I have written CSP rules in my web config file as below.

CSP in web.cofnig :

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy"
         value="default-src 'self'; connect-src *; font-src *; frame-src *; img-src * data:; media-src *; object-src *; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';"/>
```

After adding that rules it is not working and throwing below error

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Dashboard:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:8443/scss/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

CSS : (load from CSS as per mentioned below code)

```
@import url(../scss/icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css);
@import url(../scss/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css);
```

Comment: Maybe you can check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089070/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-in-a#:~:text=The%20correct%20MIME%20type%20for,HTTP%20sniffer%20such%20as%20fiddler.)

Comment: I have check mime type in IIS and it is correct and I have also checked the header value of that file request in that it is sending type text/CSS but in response, I am getting text/html

Comment: Have you checked and ensured "Static Content" in IIS Windows Features is enabled?

Comment: yes it is enable

Comment: All other CSS are loading except import CSS from the CSS